# running python sdist on a perforce project fails

Tags: python, perforce, setup.py

We are using perforce for our version control.  So when i go to build a package

```
python setup.py sdist
```

it creates a versioned folder with everything in it and then tries to delete it and fails because it contains a bunch of read-only files.  It also fails when trying to write to setup.cfg when that isn't checked out.

What is the proper way to do this from a perforce repo or any package that may have read-only files?  Do i have to check out everything first and revert unchanged?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're asking, but you can configure your Perforce workspace so that the files are left writable when they are sync'd from the Perforce server: look for the "allwrite" configuration setting in the client spec.

Comment: @BryanPendleton: That's a possibility, but I would need all developers to do it.  I'll probably just checkout to a changelist then revert unchanged.  This sort of thing works a lot better using git :)

Comment: If you want all workspaces to be allwrite, you can use a form-out or form-in trigger to arrange for that. But I don't see any problem with opening all the files for edit, then doing 'revert -a'; that's a straightforward solution too. Glad you figured out a workflow that works for you.